# Siri is called repeatedly out of control

Tags: iphone, software, siri

I face a problem with Iphone 6.
In the middle of work (particularly listening to podcasts), Siri wrongly thinks she is being called, pauses the main work, and starts asking for order. 
Edit: "Hey Siri" is not allowed in my settings.

1. Is it a hardware or software problem?
2. Is this a common problem?
3. A suggestion for a good way to solve it?

Comment: Switch off "Hey Siri" in Settings > General > Siri

Comment: "Hey Siri" is already off and this happens.

Comment: Then I'd suspect possible dirt/contamination issues with the Home button.